# copy of sheet on a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Spreadsheet "ECO" with several sheets named  "a","b","c","d"
on my program. When I copy sheet "a" to a new spreadsheet "NEWECO" ,it is ok.

```
var g2= ECO.getSheetByName("a")            
    g2.copyTo(NEWECO)
```

But when I want copy another sheet , it does not work

Example:

```
var g4= ECO.getSheetByName("c")            
    g4.copyTo(NEWECO)
```

The program says, (in French): "Une erreur s'est produite sur le serveur. Nous rechargeons actuellement votre feuille de calcul..."

It means there is error on the server side because of the sheet "c", but for sheet "a" it is OK.

So, does the problem comes from the sheet or is it a memory problem with google?

Thank you so much.

Comment: do you run these copies sequentially in the same script or is it 'one by one'? also : after refreshing the browser window does the copy exist on destination ?

Answer (score 0):

If these two fragments are parts of one script, then try to insert SpreadsheetApp.flush(); between them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to copy the data of one sheet to another, try the script below:

```js
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE'); // sss = source spreadsheet
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('SOURCE_SHEET'); // ss = source sheet
  //Get full range of data
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  //get A1 notation identifying the range
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  //get the data values in range
  var SData = SRange.getValues();

  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('TARGET'); // tss = target spreadsheet
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('TARGET_SHEET'); // ts = target sheet
  //set the target range to the values of the source data
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

Just substitute `SOURCE`, `SOURCE_SHEET`, `TARGET`, and `TARGET_SHEET` to what fits your needs.